# Return match if one match from each of two patterns found using python spaCy PhraseMatcher

Tags: python, spacy

I have multiple fragments of text, stored in a list that lets say look like this:

```
text = ['mary had a little lamb', 'julie had a little goat',
'julie enjoys eating pizza', 'mary went to the market', 
'in the market there was a lamb', 'my goat likes to drink coffee', 
'tara throws a ball for her goat', 'a goat and a kangaroo can often be friends',
'tara and mary like to drink beer']
```

I want to return a match only when a text fragment contains BOTH the name of an animal and a girls name. Hence, for the above text, I want it to return only these fragments:

```
['mary had a little lamb', 'julie had a little goat',
'tara throws a ball for her goat']
```

I get the feeling that I should be able to do this in `spaCy` by defining multiple patterns like this:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = spacy.matcher.PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)

girls_names = ['mary', 'tara', 'julie']
animals = ['lamb', 'goat']

phrase_matcher.add('GIRLS_NAMES', None, *girls_names)
phrase_matcher.add('ANIMALS', None, *animals)
```

I have got `spaCy` working a bit to match keywords generally (code below), but I have no idea how to make it flag when one word from each pattern is matched, or even to have it print which pattern is being matched.

```
for fragment in text:
doc = nlp(fragment)
matches = phrase_matcher(doc)
print('MATCHED KEYWORDS:')
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    span = doc[start:end]
    print(span.text)
print ('FRAGMENT')
print(fragment)
```

Output:

```
MATCHED KEYWORDS:
mary
lamb
FRAGMENT
mary had a little lamb
MATCHED KEYWORDS:
julie
goat
FRAGMENT
julie had a little goat
MATCHED KEYWORDS:
julie
FRAGMENT
julie enjoys eating pizza
MATCHED KEYWORDS:
mary
FRAGMENT
mary went to the market
MATCHED KEYWORDS:
lamb
FRAGMENT
in the market there was a lamb
MATCHED KEYWORDS:
goat
FRAGMENT
my goat likes to drink coffee
MATCHED KEYWORDS:
tara
goat
FRAGMENT
tara throws a ball for her goat
MATCHED KEYWORDS:
goat
kangaroo
FRAGMENT
a goat and a kangaroo can often be friends
MATCHED KEYWORDS:
tara
mary
FRAGMENT
tara and mary like to drink beer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `match_id` to match for both GIRLS_NAMES and ANIMALS in a phrase.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
phrase_matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)

girls_names = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in ['mary', 'tara', 'julie']]
animals = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in ['lamb', 'goat']]

phrase_matcher.add('GIRLS_NAMES', None, *girls_names)
phrase_matcher.add('ANIMALS', None, *animals)

text = ['mary had a little lamb', 'julie had a little goat',
'julie enjoys eating pizza', 'mary went to the market',
'in the market there was a lamb', 'my goat likes to drink coffee',
'tara throws a ball for her goat', 'a goat and a kangaroo can often be friends',
'tara and mary like to drink beer']

for fragment in text:
    doc = nlp(fragment)
    matches = phrase_matcher(doc)
    rule_ids = {nlp.vocab.strings[match[0]] for match in matches}
    if {'GIRLS_NAMES', 'ANIMALS'}.issubset(rule_ids):
        print(fragment)
```

Output:

```
mary had a little lamb
julie had a little goat
tara throws a ball for her goat
```